# non-standard value's for a new line in an asp.net textbox?

Tags: asp.net

This is the strangest thing and I can not figure out how this is happening. Some how a user on my asp.net website is creating a multiline string but is not using the normal carriage return or linefeed.

I have tried to figure out how this is being accomplished.

It is a multiline textbox and when you press enter it goes to a new line.

In the aspx code I am using the following code to break the string into an array and count the lines in the array.

```
 Dim text as String = txtMessage.Text.Trim
 Dim Array as String() = text.split(vbNewLine)

 Return Array.Length
```

I most normal situations when there is a line wrap it goes to the next line a CR/LF is entered and the code will break the string into a new line. Also pressing enter creates a new line and the split function works separating the lines and creates the dimensional array based on number of lines.

There is just one user that is some how creating a new line using a nonstandard CRLf. It is causing the split by vbnewline to not catch and break the string into an array. I have never seen this happen before.

I'm not asking how to fix this. I think I have a good idea how to keep this from happening by doing additional checks on the string through regex.

I am just completely puzzled as to how this is happening. If you have seen this before or have an idea of how this is accomplished then I would love to hear your thoughts.

Here are things I have tried: Inserting HTML into the string( didn't work )
: manually adding line breaks in the string such as \r, and using Hex codes to confuse the split function (didn't work)
:Injecting Script into the string(didn't work)
:Used access and excel to create strings without using a standard CRLF and copy and pasting (didn't work).

I have 5 yrs coding experience and am completely intrigued. Can you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you on?  VbNewline is platform-dependent -- if your server is on Windows, that means \r\n.  Since you're producing a web application, it's possible that not all of your users are on Windows -- and different OSes record line breaks differently -- they could well be VbCrLf (\r\n), VbLf (\n), or VbCr (\r), depending on whether your user is on Windows, Linux, or Mac respectively.  You'll have to detect which one the user is transmitting and split your array on the appropriate combination of characters.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306248/168057) from Karl Nicoll has more useful information for a user who experienced a very similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim. Using pl/sql Developer I am able to look at the text field and it is being stored using the standard CRLF. You bring up a good point about users being on a different OS. I am on windows. Do you think a Linux user entering a new line in the textbox could confuse the VB.net split function but still store it as a standard CRLF. This is blowing my mind!!

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen, honestly, unless something is happening to the text in between ASP.net and pl/sql to coalesce the different line endings.