# How to run HTML based sql query from MultilineTextBox?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a multiline textbox from which I am updating my sql store procedure. In my store procedure I'm sending email(Html Formated) to user via SQL Job.
Problem is when I try to put below code in my textbox my submit button is stop working and perform no action.

```
Set @link = ' <br> URL: <a href=abc.com/default4.aspx> abc.com/default4.aspx</a> <br> ' -- For Test
```

I'm also tried to put `validateRequest="false"` in my page directive but nothing happened.

Sorry here I mentioned one thing more that when I remove `<br>` tag from above code my submit button works fine. But when I put only `<br>` in my ASP.Net Textbox submit button again perform no action on submit.

How can I able to insert HTML Tags in ASP.Net Textbox.

Also I found below links regarding to my question but these links not works for me.

[Allow HTML tags in TextBox control](https://forums.asp.net/t/1581971.aspx?Allow%20HTML%20tags%20in%20TextBox%20control)

[ASP.Net Text with LineBreak from Multi-Line-TextBox to save in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883613/asp-net-text-with-linebreak-from-multi-line-textbox-to-save-in-a-database)

[ASP.NET Replacing Line Break with HTML br not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306128/asp-net-replacing-line-break-with-html-br-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on internet I found my answer.

Here I'm sharing my findings.

I put below in my page header

```
<script>
    function fnescape() {
        document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value = window.escape(document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value);
    };

    function fnunescape() {
        document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value = window.unescape(document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value);
    }
</script>
```

and put below code before closing body tag

```
<script>
    fnunescape();
</script>
```

set `ClientIDMode="Static"` to ASP.Net Textbox

**Codebehind:**

put below code inside submit button clicked

`var query = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(txtInsertQuery.Text.ToString().Trim());`

**Reference Link**

[Unescape JavaScript's escape() using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778165/unescape-javascripts-escape-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You should put HTML attribute values in double quotes;

```
<a href="abc.com/default4.aspx">
        ^                     ^
```

Also br tags should be self closed;

```
<br/>
   ^
```

Also, I don't fully understand what you mean by 'I have a multiline textbox from which I am updating my sql store procedure', but if you are having users type SQL code into a textbox this is usually a terrible idea... You should consider having them just type the URL and having this inserted into the SQL in a safe manner....

Comment: Means from textbox I am running a sql store procedure in which I am generating email.

Comment: You don't run things 'from a textbox', a textbox just takes in input...

Comment: So you are running the query straight form the text box.... do you understand why that is usually a bad idea?

Comment: Yes. I know that it is a bad idea but I need this in my testing.

Comment: As a developer I need to know how to run sql procedures from textbox. Also I know the disadvantages of it.

Comment: Why would you need to run it from the textbox? You would usually use SSMS (Management Studio) to run Ad-Hoc queries... and if your application needs to run SQL, it should have hard coded SQL statements, which you simply fill with parameters: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: If you need to have users run SQL queries... why not give them access to management studio? Instead of (insecurely) re-inventing the wheel

Comment: You're right. I need this because after our live deployment on client side we have no rights to access live database directly. So we created a Page in which we fixed bugs in our Store Procedures. Also only admin users can access that page and their log will generate.